# JasperExportManager exportReportToPdfFile creating large file (size) on server

Tags: java, spring, report

As there is something weird issue whenever i try to export report on localhost the size of file consist of small (2 megabyte) , but on the other hand whenever i try to execute that same report on server it creates almost 60 megabyte file as the data is same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe - just guessing - in the report are fonts that are installed on the client, but not installed on the server. How can Jasper produce a PDF-File when a font is not installed?

Check the fonts in the Report against installed fonts.